# Can I send locally stored python code to be run/debugged in a remote machine?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, ssh, remote-debugging, debugpy

I would like to ask if it exists any possibility to send locally stored Python code (being edited, for instance, in Visual Studio Code) to be run or debugged in a remote computer, without the necessity of having the code itself or the repository copied in the external computer. In other words, I would like to do everything vscode can do in my laptop except for debugging, which I would like to be done in an external and more powerful machine.

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Right now, I have tried to setup an external SSH session in VScode, but this only allows me to edit code stored in the remote computer. My intention is to store my code locally and use a remote interpreter/debugger, such as debugpy being run in the remote machine.

Comment: can you expose a mount/share point on your laptop that you remote could mount?

Comment: Yes. If I understand you correctly, I could connect my remote to my project folder in my laptop via SSH.

Comment: Does this help? https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/ssh#_debugging-on-the-ssh-host

Comment: Yes, but then, how can I set up a debugger in the remote machine? Or I can simply install debugpy and then access it via the standard port for debugging?